# Comment Based Help not displayed in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am trying to implement Comment Based Help as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-5.1) with Powershell 5.1 on Windows Server 2016.

The script I am using is called blah.ps1:

```
<#
.DESCRIPTION
blah blah
#>
function Blahblah
{
}
```

In Powershell, I can load the script:

```
.\blah.ps1
```

But when I ask for help on this function using:

```
Get-Help Blahblah
```

Powershell only reports an error:

```
Get-Help : Get-Help could not find Blahblah in a help file in this session. To download updated help topics type: "Update-Help". To get help online, search for the help topic in the TechNet library at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=107116.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Help Blahblah
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Get-Help], HelpNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HelpNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand
```

I am assuming that Get-Help can be used with the custom help comments. What am I missing?

Comment: @Matt - It can be declared immediately before the function block as the querent shows; however, in order to be "visible", the file name and the function name should match - that is, for the function `blahblah`, the file name should be `blahblah.ps1`, and should be in a directory that is listed in `$env:PATH`.

Comment: You should be able to move the comment-based help block after the `function` keyword and above the `param` statement.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart As described in the linked resource, the comment can be put before the function. The help works when using Import-Module to load the blah.ps1.

Comment: I don't understand your use case. Are you dot-sourcing the file? It works fine in my testing.

Comment: You don't need to put a function around the script. Import-Module does the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the script as a module instead of running it.

```
Import-Module .\blah.ps1
```

Answer (score 1):

While declaring the function, including the help immediately after the `function` header, saving it in a module, and importing the module is probably the *best* way to handle it, you can make your script's help available to `Get-Help` by ensuring that...

1. the function name and the file name match (which means one function per file), and...
2. ensuring that the script file is in a directory that is in `$env:PATH`.

The help for the function can be declared before the function itself is, provided that there is no more than one blank line between the help's closing `#>` and the beginning of the function declaration.

See [`Get-Help about_Comment_Based_Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help?view=powershell-5.1) in either the PowerShell help or the linked Microsoft documentation.